# Populating the drop down of GPValueTable

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-toolbox, user-interface

In a Python Toolbox the user has to select a city from a list of 50 world cities. More than one city can be selected.

The best UI control for that would be Autocomplete / Autosuggest, but since this does not exist I thought of a `GPValueTable` with a single column of type String. This works well when the user types in the name of the city and then clicks the plus button:
[image: manually typing city name]

And it's possible to validate it against the list of cities using `updateParameters`. However, I would like the drop down list to be populated too:
[image: drop down is empty]

The question is how can the drop down list be populated with a custom list of strings?

The code in the `getParameterInfo` function:

```
param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
displayName="Cities",
name="in_features",
datatype="GPValueTable",
parameterType="Required",
direction="Input")
param0.columns = [['String', 'Name']]
```

**Update:**

There is the option of using the out-of-the-box multi select control `multiValue=True` creates many checkboxes and the user has to scroll. Typing in the keyboard only finds items by the first letter.

[image: out of the box multiselect string]

Comment: At the moment your question contains two questions when the [Tour] says that there should be only one.  I think you should [edit] out the second one and research/ask about value lists separately.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use GPValueTable for what you are describing.  Instead try using `multiValue=True` with whatever datatype you were originally thinking about using.

For example, to turn a parameter that takes one feature class:

```
    fcParameter = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Input FC",
        name="in_fc",
        datatype="DEFeatureClass",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
```

into one that takes many, do this (note the extra parameter on the end):

```
    fcParameter = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Input FC",
        name="in_fc",
        datatype="DEFeatureClass",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input",
        multiValue=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for that @PolyGeo! Problem is that some users think there are too many items for a list box and rather type it themselves. I'll update the question with the input you provided.

Comment: A quick fix might be to add an extra optional parameter which they can type a string into, and that you can use in your code to override any choice made from the multivalued (or do nothing if left blank).